# Install .bin file without using command line

Tags: adobe

I have a .bin file that I would like to install. When I download the file and click on it within Firefox it tells me to "choose an application" to open it with. Which application do I choose? As the title says, I would like to do this without using the command line.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the command line? :)

Comment: I ended up using the command line, but it's the principle of the thing. You cannot expect the average user to adopt linux if they have to use the command line to install a program.

Answer (score 1):

When downloading the file, right-cligk on the link and select "save as", save it in some location in your hard disk (maybe Downloads). Next, open the Downloads folder, right-click on the .bin file, select "Properties" (last item). Go to the "Permissions" tab and check "Allow executing file as program". Close this dialog, and then you should be able to run the .bin by double-clicking on it.

Comment: I did this. When I click on it gives me the following message:`Could not display "/home/michael/Downloads/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin". This files is of an unknown type.` Then it offers the option to `Select Application` but it cannot find a suitable application to open the file.